# is there a way to extract words after a keyword in a search bar?

Tags: php, expression

Is there a way to extract words from a search bar, for example if someone types:
"remind me to eat more veg"
so i would be looking for all the words after "to" which in this case would be "eat more veg".
I think maybe a regular expression? or is there another way in PHP
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `explode(' ', $search_bar_string)` tada! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just tadaaaa my comment as an answer then:

```
explode(' ', $search_bar_string)
```

I would recommend to read a book on PHP tho ;)

Good luck!

Comment: I wonder that too haha. Do you want a check, sir? :P (maybe he needs a cURL too to fetch a webpage that has the search bar, may it involve an external website. Or a JavaScript action to fetch from his own webpage(s))

Comment: i cant accept the answer for a further 6 mins apparently

Answer (score 0):

I think explode is a perfectly valid answer,  but I like to promote PHP native functions whenever possible.  In this case [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) might be more useful.

```
str_word_count($search_bar_string, 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$input_string = "remind me to eat more veg";
$divide_string = "to";
$serch_result = trim ( substr($input_string, strpos($input_string, "to") + strlen($divide_string)) );
```